# return statement not working in python 3.6.3 while using functions

Tags: python

It seems that return is not working:

```
def hello(x,y):
return x
return y
```

I can't seem to return y why is this happening. I am beginner so sorry if this seems dumb to you.

Comment: `return x` ends the function. Therefore `return y` is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `x` and then `y`, how about you return them both? `return x, y`.

After a return statement you leave the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would return 2 values and call them. Return x immediately exits the function and you won't return y.

```
def hello(x,y):
    return x,y

x,y=hello(1,2)
print(x,y)
```